# How can I create a model that adds objects from other models to it

Tags: django

I am using Django 2.2 and am trying to create a model that takes information from another model. I am aware of ForeignKey however this doesn't add all of the object attributes such as title, price etc for me to call upon from my templates.

I am selling a product. This product can be for women, or it can be for men. 
I have a category selection within the model that allows me to select for men or for women. If the category selection is 'for women' then I would then like this product to become available as an object to be added to my 'for women' model. Here are my models: product, and, for women.

```
TOY_CATEGORY_CHOICES = (
    ('FW', 'For Women'),
    ('FM', 'For Men')
)

class Product(models.Model):

    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=40)
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to='media')
    title = models.CharField(max_length=150)
    description = models.TextField()
    price = models.DecimalField(max_digits=5, decimal_places=2)
    stock_quantity = models.PositiveIntegerField()
    in_stock = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    category = models.CharField(choices=TOY_CATEGORY_CHOICES, max_length=2, default='FW')
    brand = models.CharField(choices=TOY_BRAND_CHOICES, max_length=2, default='NB')
    on_sale = models.BooleanField(default=False)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title

class ForWomen(models.Model):
    product = models.ForeignKey(Product, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

Here are my views:

```
def WomenOnlyView(request):
    obj = ForWomen.objects.all()
    context = {
        'object':obj
    }
    return render (request, 'products/forwomen.html')
```

This is my URL file:

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('products/for-women/', WomenOnlyView, name='for-women'),
]
```

This is my Django Template:

```
{% block body %}
{% for product in objects %}
    <section id="catalogue">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-3">
                <div class="card">
                    <img src="" alt="Women" class="card-img-top">
                    <div class="card-body">
                        <h1>
                            {{ objects.title }}
                        </h1>
                        <p>
                            {{ objects.description }}
                        </p>    
                        <small> 
                            {{ objects.price }}
                        </small>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </section>
    {% endfor %}
{% endblock %}
```

I wish to be able to add a Product in the admin section of the website, and then this product ONLY if category == 'FW' to be accessible from within ForWomen as an object, with the title, image and price accessible.

I hope this makes some sense and someone is able to assist.

Thank you!

Comment: if `obj` is a `ForWomen` instance, then `obj.product.title` is the title.

Comment: but as ruddra points out below, there are better ways to define your models in this case. It's not clear why you'd need a separate model if all it does is have a FK to `Product`.

Comment: I have hundreds of products to put into the system, eventually, and some will be for women, some for men, some that come under other category names. Within my templates I will have a page that lists out clickable links with headers such as 'for women' and 'for men' and upon clicking on 'for women' there will be a list of all of the products which appear under the ForWomen model.

Comment: @CThomas having hundreds of products and having to filter them on category is a rather common use case and it doesn't require any additional model.

Comment: OK, so is there a way on the women's products page I can display the products that have 'for women' as a category, with a loop? i thought it would require a need to filter into a separate model of its own, but it would be much better if this didn't need to be the case!

Comment: @CThomas did you read my answer ???

Comment: Sorry, lots of people commented at once, just reading it now. If this is angering you or causing stress please feel free to exit the chat. I am still learning and new to this. It is a side project I would love to be able to complete.

Comment: @CThomas nope I'm not angry - I was just wondering if you had seen my answer since it addresses all your problems ;-)

Comment: No problem, I have and really appreciate it. Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your design is just plain wrong. You don't need those "ForWomen" or whatever models, all you have to do is to filter your products on category, ie `obj = Product.objects.filter(category="FW")`.

Also your view is wrong - you building a queryset, building a context with this queryset, but you're not passing the context to the template. You want somethin like:

```
def WomenOnlyView(request):
    obj = Product.objects.filter(category="FW")
    context = {
        'object':obj
    }
    return render(
        request, 'products/forwomen.html', context=context
        )
```

Note that you probably want to factor out common filtering operations into as either `ModelManager` or `QuerySet` methods (cf Ruddra's answer for how to create a custom manager with custom methods, and cf the official doc for [how to write a custom queryset](https://docs.djangoproject.com/fr/2.2/topics/db/managers/#calling-custom-queryset-methods-from-the-manager)).

Now your template code is plain wrong too.

First, in your context you are passing your queryset as "object" (singular), but in the template you're trying to iterate on a context variable named "objects" (plural). You have to fix either the context or the template. In your case, since what you're passing is a `QuerySet` (IOW a kind of collection), you want to fix the naming in the context (a plural on a variable name denotes a "collection" of things), IOW your view should be:

```
def WomenOnlyView(request):
    obj = Product.objects.filter(category="FW")
    context = {
        'objects':obj
    }
    return render(
        request, 'products/forwomen.html', context=context
        )
```

And then in your template, you are correctly iterating over this queryset:

```
{% for product in objects %}
     # code here
{% endfor %}
```

BUT in the loop's body, you're trying to access products attributes on the queryset  ("objects" )itself:

```
{% for product in objects %}
    <h1>
      {{ objects.title }}
    </h1>
{% endfor %}
```

What you want here is to use the iteration variable `product`:

```
{% for product in objects %}
    <h1>
      {{ product.title }}
    </h1>
{% endfor %}
```

**As a last note**: I kindly (but very strongly) suggest you take some time reading the official doc (and *do* the full official tutorial first), and possibly read more about the relational model, relational (SQL) databases, and proper relational design.

Comment: Thank you for breaking this down for me. i will try again.

Answer (score 1):

Probably a better approach is to use a [**`Proxy Model`**](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/db/models/#proxy-models). Then override the [`Manager`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/db/managers/) to get the `Products` which is made for women. For example:

```
class ForWomenManager(models.Manager):
    def get_queryset(self):
        return super().get_queryset().filter(category='FW')

class ForWomen(Product):
    objects = ForWomenManager()
    class Meta:
        proxy = True
```

It will provide an isolation from the `Product` model also you can access for women products using `ForWomen.objects.all()`.

Comment: Technically correct but mostly useless - just filter the `Product` model and you're done.

Comment: How can I filter the Product model? At the moment when I enter admin, add a new product to the Products model and select 'for women' in category, nothing is accessible from the ForWomen table. I would like it to appear as a new object in the ForWomen table.

Comment: Currently the errors I get are 'object has no attribute "title"'

Comment: @CThomas here `object` is a queryset. You need to iterate through it to get `ForWomen` objects. like `{% for obj in objects %} {{ obj.title }} {% endfor %}`